# Visualforce Page : cache attribute is behaving in an unexpected way

Tags: visuaforce

It seems that the cache attribute for an apex:page vf component doesn't allow for the use of a visualforce expression.

I am attempting to use a property of a controller to set the cache attribute for a vf page and it isn't working.

The simplest distillation of the problem seems to be as follows:

```
<apex:page cache="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <head></head>
</apex:page>
```

Works as expected. No additional meta tags are being injected into the page.

```
<apex:page cache="{!1==1}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <head></head>
</apex:page>
```

Doesn't work as expected. Even though it should be the same as above it is not. Additional meta tags are injected into the page, as if it had been set as `cache="false"`

I've tried a variety of other boolean attributes and they all seem to work just fine when I use a vf expression to set their values, for instance, `sidebar="{!1==1}"`. The cache attribute seems to act like it has been set to false if there is anything except the exact value `cache="true"`

Have I overlooked something obvious or even something known but not as obvious?

**Note:** The meta tags I'm speaking of are these.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />
```